# Consulta de configuraçao de estado do webservice GNRE

Tags: java, web-service

Estou tendo problemas em consultar as configurações de alguns estados do webservice da gnre utilizando o a receita 100099, caso utilize outra receita (100048 por exemplo), ele retorna OK, no caso da 100099, ela informa o erro:

> java.rmi.RemoteException: Erro ao gerar XML de resposta

endpoint:

https://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/gnreWS/services/GnreConfigUF

Envelope de envio

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <gnreCabecMsg soapenv:mustUnderstand="false" xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/webservice/GnreConfigUF">
            <versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados>
        </gnreCabecMsg>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <gnreDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br/webservice/GnreConfigUF">
            <TConsultaConfigUf xmlns="http://www.gnre.pe.gov.br">
                <ambiente>1</ambiente>
                <uf>MS</uf>
                <receita>100099</receita>
            </TConsultaConfigUf>
        </gnreDadosMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Envelope de retorno

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <soapenv:Code>
                <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Server.userException</soapenv:Value>
            </soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Reason>
                <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">java.rmi.RemoteException: Erro ao gerar XML de resposta</soapenv:Text>
            </soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Detail>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">sf025870.sefaz.pe.gov.br</ns1:hostname>
            </soapenv:Detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```